# SSL on Wampserver - Apache version

Tags: apache, openssl, wampserver

Ok, I would not be the least bit surprised if the answer to my question exists somewhere already. I know next to nothing about so it's possible I've been searching the wrong terms. Here's my problem:

I'm trying to update a website that requires a secure connection (https). There's no development instance of the site so I've copied the site and the database to my local wampserver. When I try to browse the site locally I get an "Unable to connect - Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost" error. I've done a bit of research and the version of apache I'm using is 2.2.22. According to the wampserver website this version does not have openssl. So I tried to update apache to v2.2.4. The update appeared to install just fine (there's an apache2.2.4 folder in c:\wamp\bin\apache), but I can't get my wampserver to switch over.

How can I move forward on this to create a self-signed certificate on my wampserver?

Comment: Are you getting specific errors when you try to enable Apache 2.2.4? Are you doing it via the taskbar wamp manager icon? Do you get any errors with `httpd -t`?

Comment: When I go to the wamp taskbar manager icon -> Apache -> Version I only see 2.2.22 as an option. I don't know anything about httpd. Although your comment made me search a bit and I see the httpd.conf file. Do I need to change the ServerRoot to point to the new instance of apache?

Comment: If you're using wampserver you can download packages, or "addons" with the different apache versions, then you can flick between then very easily. Are you saying you installed this one manually?

Comment: I installed this one from the wampserver site under Apache add-ons.

Comment: I'd consider reinstalling - if you install via the wampserver addons they should be there for you to flip between in the wampmanager tool